Why do the buttons in my loop output only affect the first output div of the loop?
I need help. I want to display user post headers with a dropdown menu. However, when the dropdown menu icon is clicked, it sends the data to the first output of the loop. The listener picks the clicked icon as if it's in the first output, and the dropdown is displayed in the first output. How can I prevent this from happening?
I expect every dropdown menu icon to be clickable, and the menu icon will be displayed next to it.
<style>
           .dropdown {
             position: relative;
             display: inline-block;
             cursor: pointer;
          }

          .dropdown-content {
           display: none;
           position: absolute;
           top: 30px; /* Adjust this value to position the menu below the icon */
           right: 0;
           background-color: #f9f9f9;
           min-width: 150px;
           box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
           z-index: 1;
          }

         .dropdown-content a {
         color: black;
          padding: 12px 16px;
           text-decoration: none;
         display: block;
          }

        </style>
    <?php
     $loggedIn = false;
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);

     if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
     $loggedIn = true;    
     $_SESSION['profile_picture'] = $user['p_p'];
     }
     require_once("db.php");
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM feed ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 12";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         
        $userId = $row['user_id'];
         $feed_id = $row['feed_id'];

        $userQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $userId";
        $userResult = $conn->query($userQuery);
 
        if ($userResult->num_rows > 0) {
            $userData = $userResult->fetch_assoc();
             
        ?>
         <div class="post-header">

        <?php
        echo '<a href="view-profile.php?id=' . $userData['user_id'] . '">';
        echo '<img src="uploads/' . $userData['p_p'] . '" class="border rounded-circle me-2  alt="Avatar"              style="height: 40px" >';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '<a href="view-profile.php?id=' . $userData['user_id'] . '"  class="text-dark mb-0">'; 
        echo '<h3>' . $userData['name'] . '</h3>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo $row['feed_id']
        ?>
         <p class="post-date"><?php  echo $row['created']?><span>

         <div class="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true" onclick="toggleDropdown()"></i>
       <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdownMenu">
       <a href="#">Help</a>
       <a href="#">Delete</a>
       <a href="#">Edit</a>
       </div>
       </div>
       </span></p>
       
       </div>

       <?php
        }  
        }
        }
       ?>

       <script>
    
       function toggleDropdown() {
       var dropdownMenu = document.getElementById("dropdownMenu");
        dropdownMenu.classList.toggle("show");
        }
 
       // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
         if (!event.target.matches('.fa-ellipsis-v')) {
          var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
         for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
         var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
       }
      }
      

}
   </script>


id attributes must be unique

echo '<img src="uploads/' . $userData['p_p'] . '" class="border rounded-circle me-2  alt="Avatar" - You're not closing your class attribute with a quote.

It would also help if you were to post your rendered HTML instead of your PHP code.

Also look carefully at the rendered HTML - it is not valid. e.g. you have divs within a span and divs within a p element. One easy way to look at the rendered HTML is in the browser devtools inspect facility. You can then copy that into a validator to sort out those problems.
